# Zoiper add pause between dialing phone numbers?

Tags: sip, asterisk, voip

I want to call an ext in a phone number .

For example **+982632601 ext 8** .

In most phones we could directly call **+982632601#8** without need to listen to IVR .

I tried following characters

```
 # * w , p
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need have support from dialplan and hardware side on asterisk server to do that.

Zoiper can do nothing with that.

What you do is calling "two stage dialling"

In asterisk it can be done via D param of dialling command something like this:

```
exten => *20,1,Dial(Local/18005558355@outbound-allroutes,,D(wwww932))
```

Sure you need parse by dialplan your number and change your dialplan to support that. You can use any character.
Sorry, dialplan for 2-stage-dialling is not trivial and out of this site topics.